OpenStreetMap - Point of Interest metadata
There are 434 columns of data extracted from osmnx for Christchurch New Zealand for a single tag.
The code:
amenity = ox.geometries_from_place(location, tags={'amenity': True}
Is there any metadata information for understanding the meaning of each column?
I want to know the metadata for the information extracted from osmnx so I can remove the columns irrelavant to my research.


Is there any metadata information for understanding the meaning of each column?

The columns contain OSM tag data, documented at OSM: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tags
Also note that the old geometries module naming has long been deprecated and will be removed in an upcoming release. It is renamed the features module.
